# React validate mongoDB dates

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, momentjs

i'm looping an `item` object values, some of the values are dates coming from mongoDB, which look like something like this  `2022-09-23T11:43:47.213Z`, with `momentJS` i want to check if `val` is date, then format it, otherwise display it as is, how to do that ?

```
<tr>
  {Object.values(item).map((val, i) => (
      <td key={i}>
         {moment(val).isValid ? moment(val).format : val} // DOESN'T WORK
      </td>
  ))}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `format` is a function and it should be called with a *format*.

```jsx
<tr>
  {Object.values(item).map((val, i) => (
      <td key={i}>
         {moment(val).isValid() ? moment(val).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a") : val}
      </td>
  ))}
</tr>
```

Note: Same goes with `isValid`. It's a function too.

Reference: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: my bad, that worked but somehow ```accountNumber``` values ```32132``` is also turned into date : )

Comment: Maybe because of [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time);

Comment: i tried ```val instanceof Date``` and ```Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Date]``` but none seems to work